# What does "distilled" mean when used in a book title?

Tags: meaning-in-context

As the title says, what does it mean?

I was looking for a "domain driven design" books but there is a book called, "[Domain-Driven Design Distilled](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0134434420)".

Does it mean it's abridged? What does "Distilled" mean in the context of book title?

Comment: It means its essence has been captured. It's impossible to say what the editors/author mean by the title, but taking it at face value it is probably something like "Essential Domain Driven Design" ... which would mean it gives you the best and most important features of that topic.

Comment: What did you dictionary say?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The second definition of distill is
**extract the essential meaning or most important aspects of.** [definition](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/distill)

So that book is probably about the essential meaning or important aspects of 'Domain-Driven Design'.

Answer (score 8):

It is a figurative concept of the chemical process of *distillation*. The Oxford English Dictionary explains it as sense 4e of the verb *to distil*.

> e. fig. To extract the quintessence of; to concentrate, purify.
>
> 1599   E. Sandys Europæ Speculum (1632) 142   This man is very charie
>   over that one remaining, and distilleth all other devises rather than
>   set finger to that string.
>
> 1600   W. Cornwallis Ess. I. xii. sig. G6v,   Time hath distild our
>   bloods.
>
> 1873   H. Spencer Study Sociol. x. 267   Men who are distilled into
>   the House of Commons, and then redistilled into the Ministry.
>
> 1889   Spectator 14 Dec. 830   We want a removable Secretary for
>   school works, not a committee, which is only the public meeting over
>   again, a little distilled.

**In terms of its use in a book title, it would suggest that a topic had been abridged and concentrated down into a more concise form than otherwise.**

Answer (score 6):

The meaning of "distill" in this sentence is the same as the literal definition:

> purify (a liquid) by vaporizing it, then condensing it by cooling the vapor, and collecting the resulting liquid.

just used *metaphorically*.  In the same way you can extract the desired alcohol from a solution of fermented material, with this book, the author claims to have *extracted* the most useful information about "Domain-Driven Design".